# Plurality of ratios: 0/1 question(s) selected

Tags: grammatical-number

How does plurality work with ratios? To me, it sounds like it should always be plural, but I'm not sure.

For each of the cases should it be questions or question?

0/0 questions selected

0/1 questions selected

1/1 questions selected

1/2 questions selected

2/2 questions selected

Comment: If there is exactly one thing, then use the singular. Otherwise, use the plural. (Decimals, for instance, are treated as plurals.) So, it should be *0/1 question* and *1/1 question*. But the rest should all use *questions*.

Comment: I would say zero out of one questions if I'm going to reference multiple values of *x*/2.